# What is the definition of algebraic equivalence of formulas?

Tags: logic, modal-logic

This question is for the propositional normal modal logic system K (although it may apply to other logics too).

I saw a couple of papers which mentioned algebraic equivalence of modal logic formulas without defining it, or referring to "two modal formulas that are provably-equivalent", i.e. $\phi$ equivalent to $\psi$ means $\vdash_K\phi$ iff $\vdash_K\psi$. But I see a problem here in that any two non-theorems would then be algebraically equivalent, which I don't believe is the intent.

So I'm thinking it may be defined as $\phi$ algebraically equivalent to $\psi$ iff $\vdash_K (\phi\leftrightarrow\psi)$, which means both $\vdash _K(\phi\rightarrow\psi)$ and $\vdash_K (\psi\rightarrow\phi)$. Then if $\vdash_K\phi$ by modus ponens  $\vdash_K\psi$ and vice-versa, which seems to be the intent. This would also allow for (only) suitable pairs of non-theorems to be algebraically equivalent formulas.

Is this correct? If not, then what is the exact definition of algebraic equivalence between formulas in K?

And b.t.w., what would be the math symbol to use for algebraic equivalence? I cannot use = because some texts use = instead of $\leftrightarrow$ inside the very formulas. And I cannot use ~ because some texts use ~ for negation. (For example, Hughes and Cresswell.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"$\phi$ is provably equivalent to $\psi$" in some logical system $K$ means that $\phi \vdash_K \psi$ and $\psi \vdash_K \phi$. If $K$ comes equipped with the usual notion of bi-implication ($\leftrightarrow$), then this will be the same as $\vdash_K \phi \leftrightarrow \psi$. I would write this as "$\phi \mathrel{\dashv\vdash}_K \psi$" (and rather illogically read this out as "$\phi$ and $\psi$ are equiprovable", even though that suggests the unintended reading that "$\vdash_K \phi$ iff $\vdash_K \psi$").

Comment: Does this definition handle the case where two non-theorems are algebraically equivalent formulas? For example, if $\phi$ is something like $pq$. If I add this to my list of formulas in a formal proof, then by uniform substitution I can prove anything, isn't it? Whereas $pq$ is algebraically equivalent to $\neg(\neg p+\neg q)$, but not to every non-theorem.
Is algebraic equivalence precisely the same thing as equiprovability?

Comment: I was explaining "provably equivalent". "Algebraically equivalent" is not standard terminology for logical formulas, as far as I know. You will need to cite the papers you have been reading that use this terminology if reading "provably equivalent" for "algebraically equivalent" does not make sense.

Comment: Yes, I saw algebraical equivalence mentioned in some course notes on modal logic, unfortunately I don't remember where. I may be wrong, or possibly they mean equiprovability, so let's consider this for now.  It's almost clear, but what I don't understand is why $\phi \vdash_K \psi$ is preferable to $\vdash_K (\phi \rightarrow \psi)$. These two are different, aren't they? Finally, is it correct to say that $p \wedge q$ and $\neg(\neg p \vee \neg q)$ are equiprovable in K (even though neither can be proven alone)?

Comment: $\phi \vdash_K \psi$ has the minor advantage of not making any assumptions about the logical language. It would make sense even if $\rightarrow$ wasn't part of the language or if the deduction theorem did not hold. And yes, $p \land q$ and $\lnot(\lnot p \lor \lnot q)$ will be equiprovable in a logic that can prove de Morgan's law. (They are not equiprovable in intuitionistic logic).